# Embed XML into Excel worksheet

Tags: c#, xml, excel, ms-office, openxml

I do have an XML file which contains several calculated values along with a list of items such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XmlContent>
  <Elements>
    <CreationDate>...</CreationDate>
    <Filename>....</Filename>
  </Elements>
  <PersonItems>
    <PersonItem>
      <FirstName>...</FirstName>
      <LastName>...</LastName>
      <Speed>...</Speed>
    </PersonItem>
    <PersonItem>
      <FirstName>...</FirstName>
      <LastName>...</LastName>
      <Speed>...</Speed>
    </PersonItem>
    [...]
  </PersonItems>
</XmlContent>
```

Now the values should be presented in an Excel sheet using Excel 2007 OpenXmlFormat. The calculated values should be mapped to a specific cell within the worksheet along `PersonItems` should be bound to a table within the same worksheet.

Is there a way to embed the XML file into the worksheet package and bind the values to the appropriate fields by using the c# Package API as a `CustomXmlPart`?

I found an example on [Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/rory/matthew-scott-application-development-using-the-open-xml-file-formats) where Matthew Scott made something similar with Word 2007 by using the [Word Content Control Toolkit](http://dbe.codeplex.com/). However, this only works with Word.

Is there something similar for Excel?

Or is there even a better approach for solving this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after research and playing around with XML mapping I came to the conclusion that there is not "easy" way to achieve that what I am longing to do.

When importing XML Content within the Excel application, Excel creates an XML mapping definition and stores it within the Package. The XML content itself will be splitted by using the mapping definition and merged within the contents of the Excel file. 
This means, that the XML file itself vanishes right after import and can no longer be used.

However, the intentional scenario is possbible with Word 2007+ as you can see in the links above.

Maybe this information is helpful for anybody who has a similar task like me.

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way is to Parse the xml file(SAX,DOM), get the corresponding attributes and values, then write those to an excel file.